# Abrir javascript com Select Option

Tags: javascript, select, option

Estou querendo abrir o abrirVit() e o abrirVelha() quando a opção do select é apertada.

```
<select>
<option href='javascript:;' onchange="abrirVit();" value="canto">Vitória - Praia do Canto</option>
<option href='javascript:;' onchange="abrirVelha();" value="velha">Vila Velha</option>
</select>
```

SCRIPT:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
    function abrirVit(){
        $("#backForm").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#formContact").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
        },150);
    };
</script>



  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
        function abrirVelha(){
            $("#backForm").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#formContact").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
            },150);
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: As funções `abrirVit` e `abrirVelha` são iguais? qual é a diferença entre elas?

Comment: Retire o `$(function(){ ... }` que está em volta das funções. Não só isso vai resolver o problema como o erro de sintaxe que tem no seu código (deve estar aparecendo no console do browser, abre pra ver).

Comment: @Sergio é só pra testar, mas elas vão fazer coisas diferentes.

Comment: @bfavaretto vou tentar agora

Comment: @bfavaretto retirei o function {} e continuo sem funcionar.

Comment: Tirou também o `};` do final?

Comment: so deixei o function abrirVIt(){ ... }

Comment: Seu jquery está declarado no header?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: Ah, eu não tinha reparado, mas o `onchange` pertence ao select, não às opções. Você chama uma função de lá e decide o que fazer com base no valor atual do select.

Comment: @bfavaretto poderia responder com um exemplo de como fazer por favor? pois não sei como vou chamar as opções pelo value

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/62f6b9tz/

Comment: @bfavaretto blz.. poderia me explicar esse 'change' ??
, agora como faço para que se no caso A for selecionado ele faça a minha função?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CONSEGUI FAZER FUNCIONAR.**

```
 <select id="opcoes">
                              <option value="selecione">Selecione uma unidade</option>
                              <option value="canto">Vitória - Praia do Canto</option>
                              <option value="velha">Vila Velha</option>
    </select>
```

script

```
  $('#opcoes').on('change', mudou);

    function mudou() {
        if ($('#opcoes').val() == 'canto'){
                 $("#backForm").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#formContact").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
        },150);
        }
        else if ($('#opcoes').val() == 'velha'){
                $("#backForm").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#formContact").css("display","block").stop().animate({"opacity":"1"},200);
        },150);
        }
    }
```

Comment: É isso mesmo. Mas você pode fazer num if só, sem sem else: `if( $('#opcoes').val() == 'canto' || $('#opcoes').val() == 'velha' ) { ...`. Já que o que você faz lá dentro é a mesma coisa pros 2 casos.

Comment: então isso era só um exemplo , pq o verdadeiro vai ter mais e eles iram fazer coisa diferentes ;D, mas obrigado amigo ajudou muito. @bfavaretto